# jquery - how to wait for variable loaded from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, tags

I have a jqyery function like this:

```
    var tagList = [];
    var suggestedTags = [];
    var tags;

    $("#tags-add").keyup(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str) || e.keyCode == 8) {
            query = $("input.tags-input").val();
            var form_data = {
                query: query
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + "ajax/tags/get_tags",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                data: form_data,
                success: function (data) {
                    tagList = data;
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
            alert("script is not working without this alert");
            loadTags();
            var tags = $('#tags-add').tags();
            $('#tags-add').tags().suggestions = suggestedTags;
            $('#tags-add').tags().restrictTo = suggestedTags;
            return false;
        }
    });

    var loadTags = function () {
        suggestedTags = [];
        $.each(tagList, function (index, item) {
            suggestedTags.push(item.tagName);
        });
    };
```

I am using bootstrap tags from here: https://github.com/maxwells/bootstrap-tags
The problem is, when i remove alert from this code, the whole autocomplete feature stops working. I tried to put load tags everywhere - in success, complete callback. I put async:false in ajax options, but still, the script is not working without an alert.
What is wrong? Please help. It took me 10 or more hours an i have no idea how to get it working.

Comment: Put all code that needs the data from an ajax call into the success function and remove the async=false. Alternatively get some code that has already been tested: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: when those code in success, any error message?

Answer (score 0):

You should load tags in either success or complete 
another approach is to use premises... 
but this way is simpler :)

```
complete: function () {
            //here you load the tags 
            loadTags();
           };
```